# I want to send a mail to admin when Rabbitmq memory or disk alarm are triggered, is there some easy way to achive this?

Tags: rabbitmq, alerts, broker, mailing, rabbitmqctl

https://www.rabbitmq.com/alarms.html

according to docs,

There are two circumstances under which RabbitMQ will stop reading from client network sockets, in order to prevent crashes. They are:

When memory use goes above the configured limit.
When disk space drops below the configured limit.

I want to send mail to admin if any of condition is breached.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: This question is tends to offtopic while it is about to recommend third-party tools. Anyway, check this link: http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html#management

Comment: thank you for reply, no i want to write code to mail, maybe a script, the tools that community provide are not alerting tools they are web based monitoring tools. What i am really looking is is there a way to know in my code that the alarm has fired for either memory or disk usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a lot of off-the-shelf tools that will do this for you. check out the [management & monitoring](http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html#management) section of the "How To" page on the RMQ website and find one that works with your existing monitoring tools.

Comment: Thanks @Derick, those are monitoring tools, i want to some how alert people and not stare at monitors, so i am looking for some kind of command or a way to actually know that some alarm is there so that i can send mails. Is that really possible ?

Comment: that's what monitoring tools do. they don't just produce graphs on screens, they give you methods to notify people when things are outside of "normal" (as defined by you in the configuration)

Comment: I am already using the management plugins, but they don't provide alerts on memory and disk usage, it shows all stats, is there a direct way to leverage that info and build a alerting framework around it ?

Comment: hey @Derick, thanks for pointing out, management tool of rabbit-mq had a rest api on top of which i wrote the wrapper to alert admin. Thanks, and accepting your answer.